# Find and replace an adjacent word with PHP

Tags: php

Delete words from two adjacent words.

```
$String = 'This is testString message.'; 
$String = preg_replace(array('/\btestString\b/'),array('test String'),$String);
echo $String;
```

I want to separate the word `testString` with `test String`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://3v4l.org/7b9a9). Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes I noticed, Because I'm viewing the cache. @axiac

Answer (score -1):

You were very close:

```
$String = preg_replace(array('/(\b)testString(\b)/'),array('\1test String\2'),$String);
```

The parenthesis and \1, \2 are there to keep what is before and after string.

Comment: `\b` is an [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php). It doesn't match an actual character. Consequently, `\1` and `\2` are [empty](https://3v4l.org/6AtP6).